# How can I correlate SignalR Write() and WriteLine() trace messages

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, system.diagnostics

I am implementing a custom, server-side `TraceListener` to redirect SignalR traces to my logging service. While testing, I implemented a default `TextWriterTraceListener` via the web.config, using direction from the [SignalR help page](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#server_text). Using `traceOutputOptions="Datetime, ThreadId, ProcessId"`, I get a trace like:

```
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(504a810d-4597-4dd7-9a93-eb49e76519d3)
    ProcessId=18508
    ThreadId=11
    DateTime=2016-01-20T15:51:05.7327980Z
```

Where the first part of the trace is like a topic and trace level, the second half of the trace is the actual message, and the `traceOutputOptions` are listed right below with an indent. I tested this with several clients connected, and the traces were always written to the file grouped correctly.

I implemented my custom `TraceListener` using the blog [here](http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/creating-a-custom-trace-listener-for-wcf). I successfully intercept the traces, but the problem is a single, typical message comes in from multiple `Write()` calls, with a final `WriteLine()` call. If I simply send the message to my logs with each `Write()` or `WriteLine()` call, they appear as completely separate log messages. Simply writing to a text file from my `TraceListener`, I get output as follows:

```
SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport Verbose: 0 : 
DrainWrites(be9bc850-1453-4c0a-b1e4-3c1ecb8b0359)
ProcessId=23604
ThreadId=7
DateTime=2016-01-20T17:04:51.3859180Z
```

The only way I can see to correlate these, is to track them by the thread `Write()` and `WriteLine()` are called on, via some sort of cache, and then send the full message to the log service on `WriteLine()`, but only if the `WriteLine()` message does not have one of the `traceOutputOptions`'s names in it, because those are also written via `WriteLine()`.

I don't want the topic and trace level to be one log line, and the message to be another. Is there any other means to make sure these would be output to the logging service together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to overwrite all the `TraceListener` `Trace*()` methods, rather than the `Write()` and `WriteLine()` methods. This gave me access to more than just a single string.